# Firebase: Failed to resolve target intent service

Tags: firebase, flutter

El App está hecha en Flutter y usa Firebase. Al compilar aparece el siguiente error en la consola:

```
E/FirebaseInstanceId( 2861): Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement
E/FirebaseInstanceId( 2861): Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.
```

No estoy seguro que implicaciones tiene el error, dado que la Aplicación compila y deja correr normalmente, pero quisiera corregirlo. Alguna idea?

Comment: seguiste todos los pasos de integración de Firebase en android ? tenías que agregar algunos extras en el build.gradle

Comment: Sip, hice todos los pasosy ha funcionado bien. Lo único que cambié recientemente fue el ID único de la Aplicación ("com.aplians.xxx"), no se si esto afecte y haya que actualizar algo en la consola de Firebase